# Path for an AutoCAD file that contain an Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, autocad

I have an embedded Excel (.xls) file in a AutoCAD (.dwg) file.
Using VBA (under Excel) I want to extract the path for the file that contains it (the path for AutoCAD file).

Answer (score 2):

If the Excel is embedded in an AutoCAD file then you will need an AutoCAD-compatible API to read the host AutoCAD DWG file. Search here for AutoCAD APIs but basically there are AutoCAD (surprise!) and the [Open Design Alliance](http://www.opendwg.org/).

If you are going straight to the embedded Excel file then it has no way of knowing that it has been embedded in anything so it won't know that path of the host AutoCAD DWG file.